# Is there some good documentation about PDF Parsing in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pdf

I am trying to find documentation, tutorials or more information about PDF Parsing with Swift. Unfortunately I cannot find any. The iOS Developer Library does have an article about it in C#.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-BAJDABJE

Is there a Swift version, or any other site that can explain PDF parsing?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial about PDF parsing to extract text: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/pdf-text-extraction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CGPDFScanner, it's available on both Objective-C and Swift. Here is the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFScanner/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read the pages but I'm not able to actually retrieve content from the pages. Feel like I'm close, I'll post a more specific question with code.

Comment: The documentation also refers to setting up 'callbacks'. I feel it's lacking on describing that part. ("You can set up the PDF scanner object to invoke callbacks when it encounters specific PDF operators in the stream.")